# User Friendly Url Ajax post

Tags: php, ajax, url, jquery

**Problem solved**

I'm using friendly url and code which is described below. I want to Request php file with ajax post. Does anybody know how to do that?

For example: I have code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/test.php",
        data: "data=test",
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
    });
});
```

When program post data to test.php file then i want to also return data from this file.

Url: http://mysite.com/admin/admin.php?m=users&a=edit&id=12

User Friendly Url: http://mysite.com/admin/users/edit/12

**Problem solved**

Comment: You'll have to write the urls manually unless the server side framework you're using can generate them for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused what you are asking about. I will assume that you just want to return some data from test.php.
if so then assuming your $data variable holds all the data, you can do this

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

and that should alret you back the data as you have it in your code

Comment: Yes. That's true. I have other problem. That code NOT run propetly when i was on url: http://mysite.com/admin/users/edit/12/. When i'am on url: http://mysite.com/admin/users then code run propetly.
Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /directory_path/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
</ifModule>
```

That's .htaccess file for user friendly url.

Thanks for help!